# How to use Future<T> interface?

Tags: java, asynchronous, parallel-processing

i am wondering how future interfaces work in java for achieving asynchronous execution.

```
Future<Map> xyz = [:]
```

Comment: You cann a function which returns a Future, you can then ask the Future if the result is known yet or not, or you simply ask the Future for the result and it will block as soon as it is present.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the [Executors framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html)

Create an ExecutorService, many types exist

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
```

Submit a task

```
Future<Integer> future = executor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {

        }
        return 123;
    }
});
```

Sometime later, use the future reference to get the result. Some possible uses

```
future.isDone(); // check if ready
future.get(); // blocks until ready or InterruptedException
future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // or wait a given time or TimeoutException
future.cancel(); // interrupt task
```

Answer (score 0):

The Executors framework as mentioned by Adam is one way to get a `Future`, but it is possible to use them in a completely different way:

Imagine a framework where you connect to a device for sending commands over the wire and expecting answers to each of them.

In this case you can put the command object, which knows about its positive and negative answers, into a "pending" queue and return a `Future` object after sending.

When the IO thread receives the appropriate answer, it can put it into the `Future` object, letting it and its users know that there is an answer.

Comment: It would be nice to leave a message about what is wrong...